# Add a dendrogram to a a plotly::subplot figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, phylogeny

Since [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157846/controlling-margins-in-a-genoplotr-plot-gene-map) doesn't seem to be responded I tried generating it myself using `R`'s `plotly`.

What I'm trying to do is plot several homologous genomic DNA segments, which are essentially horizontally laid out boxes that represent genes, and to their left a phylogenetic tree that represents the evolutionary relationships between the species of the respective genomes.

The genes belong to several groups, not all are represented in every genome.

Here is the `list` of `data.frame`s that represent the genomic DNA segments:

```
dna.segs.list <- list(data.frame(name=c(paste0("B.",1:3),paste0("C.",1:3)),y=0.2,width=0.75,group=c(rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),stringsAsFactors=F),
                      data.frame(name=c(paste0("A.",1:2),paste0("C.",1:3)),y=0.2,width=0.75,group=c(rep("A",2),rep("C",3)),stringsAsFactors=F),
                      data.frame(name=c(paste0("A.",1:2),"B.1"),y=0.2,width=0.75,group=c(rep("A",2),"B"),stringsAsFactors=F),
                      data.frame(name=c(paste0("B.",1:3),paste0("C.",1:3)),y=0.2,width=0.75,group=c(rep("B",3),rep("C",3))),
                      data.frame(name=paste0("A.",1:3),y=0.2,width=0.75,group=rep("A",3),stringsAsFactors=F))
```

Here's how I create a single plot of all of them:

```
x.range <- c(-1,9)
dna.segs.plot.list <- lapply(1:length(dna.segs.list),function(s){
  dna.seg.df <- dna.segs.list[[s]]
  dna.seg.df$group <- factor(dna.seg.df$group,levels=c("A","B","C"))
  dna.seg.plot <- plotly::plot_ly(dna.seg.df,showlegend=s==1) %>%
    plotly::add_bars(x=~name,y=~y,width=~width,color=~group,colors=c("red","blue","green")) %>%
    plotly::layout(legend=list(x=1,y=0)) %>%
    plotly::layout(xaxis=list(title=NA,zeroline=F,tickangle=45,range=x.range),yaxis=list(title=NA,zeroline=F,showgrid=F,range=c(0,1),showticklabels=F))
  return(dna.seg.plot)
})
dna.segs.plot <- plotly::subplot(dna.segs.plot.list,shareX = F,nrows = length(dna.segs.plot.list))
```

Which gives:

[image]

The problem here already is that I need to customize the legend so that I only plot it once on the one hand (otherwise it will repeat for each genome), but will include all gene groups.

Then I create the phylogenetic tree and convert it to a `ggplot` object so that I can add it to the `dna.segs.plot`:

```
tree.obj <- ape::read.tree(text="(((species1:0.08,species2:0.075):0.028,(species3:0.06,species4:0.06):0.05):0.0055,species5:0.1);")
tree.dend <- dendextend::as.ggdend(phylogram::as.dendrogram.phylo(tree.obj))
leaf.heights <- dplyr::filter(tree.dend$nodes,!is.na(leaf))$height
leaf.xs <- dplyr::filter(tree.dend$nodes,!is.na(leaf))$x
leaf.seqments.idx <- which(tree.dend$segments$yend %in% leaf.heights & tree.dend$segments$x %in% leaf.xs)
tree.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx] <- max(tree.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx])
tree.dend$segments$col[leaf.seqments.idx] <- "black"
tree.dend$labels$y <- max(tree.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx])
tree.dend$labels$x <- tree.dend$segments$x[leaf.seqments.idx]
tree.dend$labels$col <- "black"
tree.dend$segments$lwd <- 0.5
tree.ggdend <- ggplot(tree.dend,labels=F,horiz=T)+guides(fill=F)+coord_flip()+annotate("text",size=4.5,hjust=0,x=tree.dend$label$x,y=tree.dend$label$y,label=tree.dend$label$label)+labs(x="",y="")+theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),panel.grid=element_blank(),legend.position="none",legend.text=element_blank(),legend.background=element_blank(),legend.key=element_blank())
```

And finally, to combine the two I use:

```
dna.segs.tree.plot <- plotly::subplot(tree.ggdend,plotly::plotly_empty(),dna.segs.plot %>% plotly::layout(showlegend=T),nrows=1,margin=c(0,0,0,0),widths=c(0.39,0.02,0.59))
```

Which gives me:
[image]

Which is close to what I want but the issues I need help with are:

1. Having the tips of the tree and the DNA segments aligned
2. Hoe to get the tree labels not get run over by the branches as they do now
3. How to avoid getting the ---(black,solid,1) (NA,1) parts of the legend off (I'm assuming they get added due to the tree)
4. Taking care of the legend issue I described above - getting it to show all groups.

Thanks